# Strange crontab behaviour

Tags: linux, cron, python

This evening I have been playing with cron for the first time, and have started experiencing strange results.  The script that I am trying to run is a watchdog that allows me to manage a couple other scripts with a web interface.  When I run the watchdog script from a shell, `sudo ./watchdog.py` it works fine every time, and starts the scripts it is supposed to.  When I add it to crotab, `sudo crontab -e` with the line `*/1 * * * * /home/user/watchdog.py`, it does not start them, or they crash shortly after starting.  These scripts do need to run as root, so I have also tried `*/1 * * * * sudo /home/user/watchdog.py`, but nothing changed.

My question is 2 part.

1:  How do I troubleshoot this?

2:  What causes this, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1: How do I troubleshoot this?

Start by recording `stderr` and `stdout` of your script to a file (although by default `cron` should be mailing you the output).  You can do something like:

```
*/1 * * * * sudo /home/user/watchdog.py > /tmp/watchdog.log 2>&1
```

This will put any output generated by your script in `/tmp/watchdog.log`.

FYI: Note that `*/1` is identical to just `*` by itself.

> 2: What causes this, and why?

If the `requiretty` flag is set in `/etc/sudoers`, then `sudo` will only operate from a real TTY (e.g., from an interactive login session).  That's not necessarily what's happening here but it's something to check.  Look for a line along the lines of:

```
Defaults requiretty
```

in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  That got me going again.  There was one relative file path I had missed at the very beginning of the project.